# Detect current running exec command - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, exec, ssms

I have a bunch of exec commands running stored procedures, 25 of them to be precise.

```
exec stp_1
exec stp_2
exec stp_3
```

and so on...

Is there a way to know which exec command is executing? In the query window,I only see "executing query".I ran `sp_who` but can't tell which exec is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
             SELECT      r.start_time [Start Time],session_ID [SPID],
            DB_NAME(database_id) [Database],
            SUBSTRING(t.text,(r.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
            CASE WHEN statement_end_offset=-1 OR statement_end_offset=0 
            THEN (DATALENGTH(t.Text)-r.statement_start_offset/2)+1 
            ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2+1
            END) [Executing SQL], 
            Status,command,wait_type,wait_time,wait_resource, 
            last_wait_type
FROM        sys.dm_exec_requests r
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) t
WHERE       session_id != @@SPID 
AND         session_id > 50 -- don't show system queries
ORDER BY    r.start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
DMExQryStats.last_execution_time AS [Executed At],
DMExSQLTxt.text AS [Query]
FROM
sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS DMExQryStats
CROSS APPLY
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DMExQryStats.sql_handle) AS DMExSQLTxt
ORDER BY
DMExQryStats.last_execution_time DESC
```